# yii2 multiple value show in single query for group concat not working?

Tags: yii, yii2

I have the list of records in the subject table then I want to add to group_concat of yii2 bind methods.

```
Table Structure
===============
id, sname
1   english
2   maths


$datas = Subjects::find()->select("Group_concat(sname)")->where('FIND_IN_SET(id,"1,2")')->one();                                 
return $datas->sname;
```

but I have to get the single value only. I want result is "English, maths" but my result is "English" only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should assign a name to the result using alias  ..  eg  g_sname

```
$datas = Subjects::find()->select("Group_concat(sname) as g_sname")
        ->where('FIND_IN_SET(id,"1,2")')
        ->one();                                 
return $datas->g_sname;
```

you could also try using column()

```
$concatName = Subjects::find()->select("Group_concat(sname) as g_sname")
        ->where('FIND_IN_SET(id,"1,2")')->column()
        ->one();                                 
return $concatName  ;
```

Comment: Above coding has been very correct. but, i g_sname is not in model some i got some error. so i declare in public variable.

Comment: if you need  a calculated column  you should add  a public var at the beginning of the model  eg: public gSname;

Comment: i have update the answer with some suggestion .. hope are useful